# Swift HTML content of URL of mobile site

Tags: html, swift, xcode, mobile

I've got a URL and I'm trying to get the HTML content of the site the following way:

```
func getHtml(_ urlString: String) -> String? {

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .ascii)
        return html
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

if let html = getHtml("https://m.youtube.com/") {
    print(html)
}
```

My issue is, that this gets me the html of the desktop version of the site, however I need the html of the mobile version.

I'm not looking for a workaround for this specific site, but for a general solution, so that, given any URL of a mobile site, it doesn't default to getting me the html of the desktop site.

Comment: Are you developing this for iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Viewcontroller in iOS to get the HTML, you can use hidden **WKWebView** as an alternative and implement the **WKNavigationDelegate** which has the didFinish method where you can use **webView.evaluateJavaScript**. As wkwebview is loading from mobile, you will get the mobile version html. Here is the sample of the code.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class YourViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
     let webView = WKWebView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func BtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        loadWeb(url: "https://m.youtube.com/")
    }
    func loadWeb(url: String) {
        if let myURL = URL(string: url) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML") { (data, error) in
            //use html data 
            print("data", data, error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been considering this solution. My worry was, that this would use significantly more data than just downloading the html, since it loads all the images on the page. I'll be requesting the page frequently to monitor a value, potentially on mobile data. However, it turns out that the webview buffers all the images, so refreshing frequently isn't a problem. Thanks I'll probably do it this way.